# Usage of Interlocked.CompareExchange for deciding whether a property has been changed by another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, datetime, windows

I'm developing a Windows Service that receives data from somewhere and saves it to DB one time per 5 minutes. The Service is multithreaded and I actually got problems when several threads saved data at same minute (no thread sync was implemented).

Now I've implemented it and am looking for code-review and optimizations.

```
class DataProccessor
{
    private int _lastMinutesUpdate;
    private readonly Timer _saveTimer = new Timer(TimerTick, null, _settingsProvider.SaveInterval, Timeout.Infinite);

    private void TimerTick(object state)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var initialLastMinutesUpdate = _lastMinutesUpdate;
        var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var currentDateMinutes = currentDate.Minute;
        var fiveMinUpdate = currentDateMinutes % 5 == 0 &&
                            currentDateMinutes != initialLastMinutesUpdate &&
                            initialLastMinutesUpdate == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _lastMinutesUpdate, currentDateMinutes, initialLastMinutesUpdate);
        if(fiveMinUpdate)
        {
            // Insert values to DataBase
        }
        // TimerTick will be called in interval from settings minus time spent to TimerTick execution.
        _saveTimer.Change(Math.Max(0, _settingsProvider.SaveInterval- watch.ElapsedMilliseconds), Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you running `TimerTick`?

Comment: @svick Thanks for your reply! I've extended my code, please check it out.

Comment: Your extended code won't compile. Could you post code that actually works?

Comment: What I don't understand about the code: 1. Why the complicated logic around `SaveInterval` and 5 minutes? If the save should be done every 5 minutes, why not use that as the timer interval? 2. Why do you use `CompareExchange` to update `_lastMinutesUpdate`? Is there some other code that could change it?

Comment: Are there multiple `DataProcessor` objects, or just one?  Are there multiple `Timer`s calling each instance's `TimerTick` or just one?

Comment: @svick 1) I need to save values to DB every 5 minutes and send current values to clients every SaveInterval ms. 2) Yes, another thread that executes TimerTick. SaveInterval is 200 ms now.

Comment: @Snowbody Just one. The bottleneck is TimerTick handler that can be executes by several thread simultaneously as SaveInterval is just 200 ms.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the only way to have two threads update that value simultaneously is if `TimeTick` gets invoked twice in a very short amount of time.  Given a sane value for your time interval, this can't happen.  And if it can, you would typically use a `Monitor` and quickly exit the second handler.

It seems that you are invoking this timer at a much higher rate than necessary - every 200ms - because you want to do something else that frequently, so you have code to check if you should do your 5 minute job now.  There isn't a good reason to have one callback responsible for two totally different things.  You should be able to solve this by having a 5 minute timer for the database job and a 200 ms timer for the broadcast, and these would each call their own callback function.

Comment: My interval is 200ms. Ok, I can and I actually replaced Interlocked.CompareExchange by lock, but the question was what's wrong with my code (I still can't find a place where synchronization breaks).

Comment: You have a 200ms timer for a task that you want to happen every 5 minutes???

Comment: Just set the interval to 5 minutes and get rid of those pointless comparisons.

Comment: One more time: I need to save values to DB every 5 minutes and send current (actual) values to all connected clients every _SaveInterval_ ms.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that in the code.  Why don't you have 2 timers for 2 different jobs?

Comment: Good question, this will really make things easier. Update your answer and I'll mark it as a solution.